# Why is the output 30 and not 31?

Tags: java, increment

```
public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myFirstNumber =20;
        int mySecondNumber=10;
        System.out.println(myFirstNumber+++mySecondNumber);
    }
}
```

**mySecondNumber** should have been incremented to `11`, thus making the sum `31`

Comment: Why do you think "myFirstNumber+++mySecondNumber" means "myFirstNumber+(++mySecondNumber)" and not "(myFirstNumber++)+mySecondNumber"? What's your proof? The output already disproves you.

Answer (score 9):

It's the Java parser interpreting

```
+++
```

as `(myFirstNumber++)+`, rather than `+(++mySecondNumber)`

We use the term **greedy** to describe that behaviour; i.e. the parser consumes as much of the input as it can in order to form a meaningful expression.

Be assured, that after the `println`, `myFirstNumber` will be 21.

Comment: I understand it well now. I just checked myFirstNumber and it had incremented. Thanks.

Comment: @Chronic - Another way of looking at this is the Java compiler is **punishing** you for writing unreadable code.  ;-)